# What is the best administrative level for autocompleting addesses in German cities

Tags: html, localization, autofill

The `autofill` attribute for postal addresses has [4 different "administrative levels"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Administrative_levels_in_addresses). The documentation gives some examples for the US, UK, China and Japan. I would like to know if there is some specification for cities in German addresses (or a table of how ALL countries structure their administrative level). For Germany, using `address-level1` and `address-level2` would both make sense for cities:

- `address-level1` because usually we don't include the county (Bundesland) in addresses, so using the "highest" level makes sense, mimicking how things are specified for UK addresses.
- `address-level2` because if you want to be very specifc, it is level 2 of an address, level 1 being the county.

Any official reference or data that would back up either?

Answer (score -1):

I'd say, `address-level2` is what you need for German addresses.

[The specs say](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-address-level2):

> The second administrative level, in addresses with two or more administrative levels; **in the countries with two administrative levels, this would typically be the city, town, village, or other locality within which the relevant street address is found**

---

Here's what I use:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="address-line1" placeholder="Straße und Hausnummer"/>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="postal-code" placeholder="PLZ"/>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="address-level2" placeholder="Stadt"/>
</form>
```

And if you want to split street name and house number, you would need to use a workaround:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="address-line1" placeholder="Straße"/>
  <!-- "address-level4" is used as a workaround, because Chrome ignores `autocomplete="off"` -->
  <input type="text" autocomplete="address-level4" placeholder="Hausnummer"/>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="postal-code" placeholder="PLZ"/>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="address-level2" placeholder="Stadt"/>
</form>
```